# How to get current timestamp in proxy-wasm-go-sdk

Tags: go, istio, webassembly, envoyproxy, tinygo

When using a WasmPlugin with Istio 1.12 and proxy-wasm-go-sdk, it seems that stdlib-functions like `time.Now()` are not available, and I have not found an alternative. However, there is [GetProperty()](https://pkg.go.dev/github.com/tetratelabs/proxy-wasm-go-sdk@v0.16.0/proxywasm#GetProperty) function, which allows to access some [request properties](https://www.envoyproxy.io/docs/envoy/latest/intro/arch_overview/advanced/attributes) like `request.time`.

So I ended up with something like

```
requestStart, err := proxywasm.GetProperty([]string{"request", "time"})

proxywasm.LogInfof("len %v", len(requestStart))
requestStartTs := binary.LittleEndian.Uint64(requestStart)
proxywasm.LogInfof("request.start %v", requestStartTs)
```

It prints

```
2022-02-15T17:48:18.806485Z info    envoy wasm  wasm log redacted: len 8
2022-02-15T17:48:18.806516Z info    envoy wasm  wasm log redacted: request.start 1644947298806002000
```

Now this seems to be a Unix timestamp with that given time, but I am not at all sure if I have got this right.

Is there maybe a less low-level method to get a current timestamp?

Answer (score 1):

Time library should be available. Did you import it in your go file ?
Example : https://github.com/tetratelabs/proxy-wasm-go-sdk/blob/main/examples/helloworld/main.go

Comment: Ok so it seems that using exactly
`time.Now().UnixNano()` does work, but only `time.Now()` does not. 

got some error like in https://github.com/proxy-wasm/proxy-wasm-cpp-host/issues/199 it seems to cause timezone stuff to be required..